# React-cant see anything after using route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, react-router-dom

So I'm trying to make an app where you fill out a survey and then go to another page.
I've tried using React Router for this. I followed a tutorial but when I try to render components with Route in them it doesn't seem to render. components without Route seem to work fine.

main app:

```
import Intro from "./pages/intro.js"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Intro/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

component with Route:

```
import { Routes, useNavigate, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import B1 from "./B1.js"

function Intro() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigateToB1 = () => {
    navigate('./B1.js');
  };

  return (       
    <form>
      <h1>Walcome!</h1>
      <p><b>plase enter your name:</b></p>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </label>
      <input
        type="submit"
        id="sumbit"
        value="Submit"
        onClick={navigateToB1}
      />
    
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="./B1.js" element={<B1 />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Intro;
```

Comment: make sure you're using the correct ```react-router-dom``` version that corresponds to the correct route components

Comment: Are you exporting App to index.js?

Comment: yes as I mentioned components without Route works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

The `Intro` component can't use the `useNavigate` hook since it's the component rendering the `Router` component that provides the routing context the `useNavigate` hook needs. `Intro` is also incorrectly using the low-level `Router` component which is missing a couple required props.

[Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router)

> ```
> interface RouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   location: Partial<Location> | string; // <-- required!!
>   navigationType?: NavigationType;
>   navigator: Navigator;                 // <-- required!!
>   static?: boolean;
> }
> ```

The higher-level routers, (*`BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`, etc...*) manage this themselves.

The `Intro` component is also rendering a `form` element and not preventing the default form action from occurring when the form is submitted. Not doing this will result in reloading the page and remounting the entire React app.

## Solution

Use one of the higher level routers and render it higher in the ReactTree than any component that needs to access its routing context.

Example:

App

```
import { BroswerRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Intro from "./pages/intro.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Intro />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Intro

Remove the router and consume the `onSubmit` event object in the `navigateToB1` handler to prevent submitting the form.

```
import { Routes, useNavigate, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import B1 from "./B1.js";

function Intro() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigateToB1 = (e) => { // <-- consume onSubmit event object
    e.preventDefault();         // <-- prevent the default form action
    navigate('/B1.js');
  };

  return (       
    <form>
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      <p><b>Please enter your name:</b></p>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </label>
      <input
        type="submit"
        id="submit"
        value="Submit"
        onClick={navigateToB1}
      />
    
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/B1.js" element={<B1 />} />
      </Routes> 
    </form>
  );
}

export default Intro;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare your routes in the app.tsx or .js  file. But that is up to you in general you declare your route in the child component if you want to add to the current route. Let's say your component route to '/Intro' then you put routes into the 'Intro' component to get directed to '/Intro/B1.js'

Also react-router has a new version: 6. Be careful to not look at the wrong version for docs.
About using 'Router' Component: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router. BrowserRouter will probably fit your needs

> Type declaration
>  is the low-level interface that is shared by all router components (like  and ). In terms of React,  is a context provider that supplies routing information to the rest of the app.

> You probably never need to render a  manually. Instead, you should use one of the higher-level routers depending on your environment. You only ever need one router in a given app.

> The  prop may be used to make all routes and links in your app relative to a "base" portion of the URL pathname that they all share. This is useful when rendering only a portion of a larger app with React Router or when your app has multiple entry points. Basenames are not case-sensitive.

Try this:

```
function Intro() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigateToB1= () => 
  {
    navigate('./B1.js');
  };

    return ( 
    <>      
        <form>
            <h1>Walcome!</h1>
            <p><b>plase enter your name:</b></p>
            <label>
             Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" id="sumbit" value="Submit" onClick={navigateToB1} />
    
       </form>
       <BrowserRouter>
           <Routes>
              <Route path="./B1.js" element={<B1/>} />
           </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter

  </>
  );
  }

  export default Intro;
```